# How to access CSS variables inside props function of styled components?

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components, react-props, css-variables

I have a React app. It is using styled components.
In the main.css file, I have defined a variable like -

```
:root {
  primaryColor: 'red';
}
```

In the React app, I have styled components like (not working) -

```
const myDiv = styled.div`
  color: ${props => props.color? props.color : var(--primaryColor)};
`;
```

// Not working

If I use the styled component as (working) -

```
 const myDiv = styled.div`
  color: var(--primaryColor);
 `;
```

It works.

How to make the first case work? which is to access the css variable inside the styled component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are inside an expression that returns the content of `props.color` or a string that includes the `var` expression. Since it's a string you need to wrap it with quotes.

```js
const MyDiv = styled.div`
  color: ${props => props.color? props.color : 'var(--primaryColor)'};
`;

ReactDOM.render(
  <MyDiv>Some text</MyDiv>,
  root
);
```

```css
:root {
  --primaryColor: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/styled-components/4.4.0/styled-components.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```